# Dealing with Excessive .idx File Growth and Reducing Database Size in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs-2017

I'm using TFS 2017, and I'm experiencing a significant daily increase in storage usage. I've followed various guides, including running procedures like `prc_deleteunusedcontent` and `prc_deleteunusedfiles`, and `shrink the database`. Additionally, there are no automated build or test jobs configured for any projects on it.

Upon investigation, I've noticed that the file `.idx` (git pack index) in the `tbl_content` table grows to a large size upon generation. For instance, when I create a branch 'A' from 'develop,' make a minor text file change, commit, and push, the `.idx` file balloons to around 6MB while the pack file remains very small (<0.01MB).

I've also referred to this article to verify that the file size increases immediately after pushing (repeating the process multiple times to ensure consistency): [TFS Internals - How does TFS store Git repositories?](https://www.richard-banks.org/2014/02/tfs-internals-how-does-tfs-store-git.html).

I've learned that TFS 2017 does not support the `git gc` command. Can anyone provide guidance on reducing storage usage in this situation?
Thank you very much!

Comment: You should strongly consider using a version of TFS (now, Azure DevOps Server) more recent than 6 years old. You'll likely find that the problem solves itself if you do that.